# XML serialization reflecting type

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, reflection, xml-serialization

In Visual Basic.NET, I am having some trouble serializing an object to XML.

Here is the class I am trying to serialize:

```
<Serializable> 
Public Class ClassTest
    Public string1 As String
    Public string2 As String
    Public ListOfString As List(Of String)
    Public dreamscript As New DreamScript
End Class
```

Here is the function I am using to serialize the object:

```
    Public Sub SerializeObjectToXML(FileName As String, ObjectToSerialize As Object, ObjectType As Type)
        Dim Serializer As New XmlSerializer(ObjectType)
        Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(FileName)
        Serializer.Serialize(Writer, ObjectToSerialize)
        writer.Close()
    End Sub
```

Here is the error:

> There was an error reflecting type 'CanLucidDream.ClassTest'.

At this line:

```
Dim Serializer As New XmlSerializer(ObjectType)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the reason: Message=System.IO.FileInfo cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Can I have an explanation of how to setup a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Please, include the full stack trace. The source code of DreamScript class is important too.

Comment: Most likely something in the `DreamScript` class that is messing up serialization. Can you show us the code where you call that sub?